# Python Syntax " G = {i: [] for i in range(len(l))}"

Tags: python, syntax

I am relatively new to Python, and I am not sure what exactly this statement does. I haven't been able to find anything with a syntax like this in my course books either. I assume it declares an array? but I am nit sure.

**What exactly does this statement mean/do?**

```
 G = {i: [] for i in range(len(l))}
```

(If anyone is able to explain it to me in Java equivalent, that would be easier as I know Java pretty well)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This thing in python is called **dict-comprehension**. i.e, we can write any logic in a single line and return a dict.

In your case `{i: [] for i in range(len(l))}`, it is equivalent to this;

```
G = {}
for i in range(len(l)):
    G[i] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), so it'll create a dictionary mapping the ints 0-(N-1) where N is the length of the list to empty lists

```py
>>> {index: list() for index in range(5)}
{0: [], 1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: []}
```